# Transfer Blend files into a different location: How to avoid missing files/textures/etc?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data, packing

I need to reorganise my blender folder and move it to another PC and I am afraid that i might lose some linked texture/image sequences/etc that are used in the .blend files.

What should i do to avoid that?

1. Pack all data into the blend files
2. Make all paths relative

?

thank you for your help.

Comment: you can open your file and go to data->save as. there you can save your file in your new folder structure and set the link paths, so the links should work though.

at least i used to do this, when i have to move files with linked content.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file/82965#82965 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63251/packing-image-and-movie-strips/63253#63253