# SheepIt upload warning, Files not found

Tags: rendering

I started using SheepIt today and I tried uploading my first .Blend onto it. After I uploaded it, I got this error message. I had already used the *Find Missing Files* Function, and the *Pack All in .Blend* Function to get these files into the .Blend, but it still thinks these two files are missing. Does anybody know what to do? Thanks! [image]

Comment: It would help if you added some information about your scene. The "Pack All" function will only pack images into the file. It will not pack simulation caches, video files, image sequences.

Comment: The Face_1 and FaceB_1 were both part of image sequences. Is there a way I can also pack them into the scene?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63251/packing-image-and-movie-strips/63253#63253

Answer (score 0):

I use sheepit too!

This error comes up when you are missing image files, caches, or other external sources which are required in the rendering process. In this case, I would check the box in Blender under File **>** External Files **>** Automatically pack into .blend.

This should do the trick.

If not, then you would have to take the image files and pack the into a .zip file with the blender file. You would have to make sure that the image directory in Blender for the images is set to local in the file, so that it would find it on any computer. (Which is how sheepit works.)